# Como separar em pares os digitos de uma variável em C#?

Tags: c#

Como eu pego uma variável que possui um valor de 4 dígitos, dividir esses dígitos em pares e salva-los em outras variáveis?

exemplo: 3025 = 30 25

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser dividir qualquer número inteiro, sem converter para *string*, e com suporte para tamanho de agrupamento arbitrário:

```
using System.Collection.Generic;

long[] DividirNumero(long valor, int tamanhoGrupo)
{ 
    if(tamanhoGrupo <= 0)
        return new [] {valor};

    int localTamanhoGrupo = (int) Math.Pow(10, tamanhoGrupo);
    Stack<long> resultado = new Stack<long>();
    valor = Math.Abs(valor);

    do 
    {
        resultado.Push(valor % localTamanhoGrupo);
        valor /= localTamanhoGrupo;

    } while (valor > 0);

    return resultado.ToArray();
}

// 1234 (tamanho agrupamento 0) => 1234
// 1234 (tamanho agrupamento 2) => 12 34
// 1234 (tamanho agrupamento 3) => 1 234
// 123456789 (tamanho agrupamento 2) => 1 23 45 67 89
// 123456789 (tamanho agrupamento 6) => 123 456789
// 123456789 (tamanho agrupamento 1) => 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
// 9223372036854775807 (tamanho agrupamento 3) => 9 223 372 36 854 775 807
// 2147483647 (tamanho agrupamento 2) => 21 47 48 36 47
// -2147483648 (tamanho agrupamento 2) => 21 47 48 36 48
```

(Pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3f1KRJ)).

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta está bem vaga, não dá pra saber o tipo da variável e qual seria o propósito disso, mas considerando que seja uma string, pode-se fazer assim:

Exemplo utilizando 5 valores para exemplificar:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] valores = new string[]{"3025","302","","1","12345"};


        for (int i =0; i < valores.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valor " + (i + 1)+":");
            string p1 = valores[i].Substring(0,valores[i].Length/2);
            string p2 = valores[i].Substring(valores[i].Length/2);


            Console.WriteLine("Parte 1: "+ p1);
            Console.WriteLine("Parte 2: "+ p2);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");

        }

    }
}
```

> Resultado:

```
Valor 1:
Parte 1: 30
Parte 2: 25
------------
Valor 2:
Parte 1: 3
Parte 2: 02
------------
Valor 3:
Parte 1: 
Parte 2: 
------------
Valor 4:
Parte 1: 
Parte 2: 1
------------
Valor 5:
Parte 1: 12
Parte 2: 345
```

Answer (score 0):

Este método suporta qualquer tipo de elemento, desde que seja enumerável. De princípio, declare o seguinte método:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Splits an array into several smaller arrays.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">The array to split.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The size of the smaller arrays.</param>
    /// <returns>An array containing smaller arrays.</returns>
    internal static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(T[] array, int size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
        {
            yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
        }
    }
```

Para usar em uma **String**, você fará o seguinte:

```
string palavra = "30250892";
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> conjuntos = Split(palavra.ToCharArray(), 2); // não se esqueça do ToCharArray()

foreach (IEnumerable<char> par in conjuntos) {
     string parFormatado = string.Join("", par);
     Console.WriteLine(parFormatado);
}

// 30
// 25
// 08
// 92
```

Você pode usar este método em qualquer tipo, desde que esteja enumerado (em listas).

---

Créditos do método [Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986129/c-splitting-an-array-into-n-parts/18987605).